# How to deal with php POST when form is dynamic

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My client page (form builder) is dynamic, i.e. User can build a form with 2 text areas and 1 text field or any amount needed.

Ive been able to do it and change their IDS too. Now I have to send these data to server side PHP.

Now what if the user enters more fields or less? like 5 text areas 10 text fields. How can Write the server side code?

Client side e.g

```
<textarea type="text" name="TxtArea1" /></textarea>
<textarea type="text" name="TxtArea2" /></textarea>
<input type="text" name="Txt1" />
```

Ajax post e.g

```
$.ajax(
{
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
data : postData,
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
{
    $("#main").load("test.php");            
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
    $("#main").load("An err occured");          
}
```

Server side e.g

```
$f1 = $_POST[ 'TxtArea1' ];
$f2 = $_POST[ 'TxtArea2' ];
$f3 = $_POST[ 'Txt1' ];
```

Comment: cant you use array? `<textarea type="text" name="TxtArea[]" /></textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array notation to have your form elements show up as an array on the server side in the respective $_POST index

```
<textarea type="text" name="TxtArea[]" /></textarea>
<input type="text" name="Txt[]" />
```

Then you can loop over `$_POST['TxtArea']`